# Every video starts with black and messy screen in a while

Tags: video, graphics-card

When I start a video on my laptop it is messy in the first 4-5 seconds. It does not depend on where I play it, everywhere I get the same problem. The problem looks like this:

[image: image is here]

I have a Toshiba Satellite L500-1XR with an ATI Radeon HD5145 GPU. I tried to reinstall the driver, but it did not help.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to pull out a can of compressed air and give your laptop fan vents a good breeze. I suggest going ahead and doing so *before* you double check for hightemps via a tool like speedfan.

Comment: What does it has to do with such a problem ?

Comment: "'It's just dust.' I used to think that. Heat kills electronic components. Also, computers limit themselves if they aren't being cooled. A literal plug of dust can form behind the heatsink of a laptop. Use canned air - NOT a vacuum." ~http://www.decentsecurity.com/#/holiday-tasks/ an HD5xxx is, relatively speaking, _ancient_; TeraScale 2 (on which the gpu is based) was launched nearly six years ago; that's lots of time to get vents clogged and silicon cooked. My experience is that discreet GPUs (and chipset graphics) are more sensitive to heat than CPUs/APUs. Better airflow alone may help.